# Zend framework 2 require.js via RdnRequireJs Module

Tags: zend-framework2, requirejs

I wanted to get into require.js to structure my js files in a cleaner manner. So I stumbled uppon [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), after a little bit of diggin and understanding how require.js works I realized getting it to do what I want out of the box would be a rather hard task since it's using it's own scope and what not. So I figured it wouldnt go well with zf2 because of the way it works.

After a litle search I stumbled uppon a 2 year old zf2 module [SxRequireJs](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/SxRequireJs). But having to play arround with my vhosts and mod rewrites I decided against it and found this [RdnRequireJs](https://github.com/radnan/rdn-require-js). Now I followed all the installation steps and have the following setup.

```
//application.config.php
//After successfully installing it trough composer I added the namespace
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'ZfcBase',
    'ZfcUser',
    'RdnRequireJS',
),
```

After that I created a `Bar.js` file within my `/public` directory and added these definitions within.

> // Stripped file names of .min to simplify the calling here
>
> define(['./html5shiv'], function(shiv) {
>       shiv.log('Hello World!'); });
>
> define(['./respond'], function(resp) {
>       resp.log('Hello World!'); });
>
> define(['./jquery'], function(jq) {
>       jq.log('Hello World!'); });
>
> define(['./bootstrap'], function(twboot) {
>       twboot.log('Hello World!'); });

after that I overide the RdnRequireJS config within my `global.php` like so:

```
return array(
'rdn_require_js' => array(
        'library' => '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js',

        'config' => array(
            'baseUrl' => '/modules',

            'paths' => array(
                'App' => 'app/js'
            ),

            'packages' => array(
                'App'
            ),

            'shim' => array(),

            'deps' => array(),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now I tried to use the viewHelper to get my inline scripts going like suggested within the documentation of RdnRequireJS.

I called `<?php $this->requireJS('Bar') ?>` within my `layout.phtml` and within a module's `index.phtml` without any success. The viewHelper returns 'NULL' without any error message what so ever. I changed the configuration to a local `require.js` file without any success either. Then renamed the `rdn_require_js` configs baseUrl to module rather then modules but that didnt get me anywhere either.

The github did not seem to have much contribution nor a wiki or any issues. So I'am wondering if any of you guys actually got it up and running? Help would be much appriciated.

Thanks for your time.

Edit: I forgot to mention I also added the folders `app/js` which stores my current js files within my projects root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to get it to work i do get it to load both the Bar.js and Foo.js files. It tries to load them from the /modules subfolder in public defined in the config

```
'config' => array(
        'baseUrl' => '/modules',
```

The viewhelper itself is not suppose to return any output. it just adds the file "Bar" to your deps. Which requireJs will try to load from the "baseUrl"

RdnRequireJS then adds the script at the end of your html. something looking something like this

```
var require = {"baseUrl":"\/modules","paths":{"App":"app\/js"},"packages":["App"],"shim":[],"deps":["Bar"]};
```

Which requireJs will load.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you! I narrowed the problem down. If I invoke the viewhelper trough my module.php It works. If I do it within my views it doesnt. So I suppose there is something else wrong within my viewhelper configs somewhere.